# LinkedIn summary -- mixed messages

Tags: linkedin, developer, first-job

I'm in the process of creating my LinkedIn profile to apply for my first full stack development job.

I'm getting mixed messages about the summary section, which everyone agrees is important, but to which there seem to be two approaches.

1. Lots of detail about what drives you, your experience, your philosophy etc. This is recommended by many blogs about the topic, where examples involve 3-5 paragraphs of text, including personal details. ([example 1](https://www.codementor.io/learn-programming/9-linkedin-profile-tips-for-junior-developers), [example 2](https://business.linkedin.com/talent-solutions/blog/linkedin-best-practices/2016/7-linkedin-profile-summaries-that-we-love-and-how-to-boost-your-own)).
2. Brief summary including goals and a list of skills/technologies that one uses -- 1 paragraph and a bullet list. This is what I see on most senior developer profiles. ([example 1](https://www.linkedin.com/in/vipin-kundal-a70448a8/?trk=public-profile-join-page) [example 2](https://www.linkedin.com/in/studentsample/)). The second example is LinkedIn's own student example.

The advantages of 1 are obvious: I can say more to a potential employer, which is great for someone with a limited number of past projects. But if other developers have short summaries, I'm concerned mine will come across as a wall of text and possibly pretentious.

[This](https://www.linkedin.com/in/david-rowthorn/) is my current profile with a relatively short summary. (Project and experience sections are not complete yet.)

So, **which approach should I go for in my current situation?**

Comment: It doesn't make much difference.  People barely glance at LinkedIn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a read of your summary section. Apart from some spelling (`tech` instead of `technologies` for example), I would say it's fine.

I myself would maybe see if I could leave out the last paragraph to avoid having to update it regularly (as I switch projects like I get coffee).

That which you have written in your last summary paragraph is more for a specific job description (even something a self-employed job (for yourself) just to describe the project instead of in the summary). If it concerns just a project, you might want to add it as an "Accomplishment", create a new project for your profile here:

[image: add stuff button]

Depending on where you are on LinkedIn that button appears in the top right of the page (when editing your profile) or underneath your profile picture (when viewing your own profile)

---

Additionally there should also be a section in which you can see what LinkedIn thinks about your profile. This takes into account how well you can be found, usage of keywords, and filled out content (descriptions for jobs, educations, projects, et cetera). Should look something like this. Mine is "all-star" and no longer shows any buttons, yours might be different.

[image: profile ranking by li]

Comment: Nice job integrating the screen shots!

Comment: Thanks @MisterPositive. If your on Windows, you can create these too, search in Start menu for "Snipping tool". Next to Paint, it's the best ;)

Comment: Excellent advice. I'm now up to all star and am adding projects. Since I'm new to the industry, I'm putting these under 'Experience', since these comprise a large part of my relevant experience.